# Can't get Javascript timeout event to execute

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, timeout, settimeout

I have a onClick function that works to move boxes on and off the webpage when the screen is clicked. I'm trying to convert this code so that the movement will happen automatically every four seconds. The problem is that the timeout event most likely needs to be happening inside the main function, because of the functions already repetitive nature, and that's where I'm stuck.

This is the working code:

```
<script>

    $('.box').click(function() {
        $('.box').each( function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        }
    });

    $(this).animate({
        left: '-56%'
    }, 500);

    if ($(this).next().size() > 0) {
        $(this).next().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $(this).prevAll().last().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    }
    });

</script>
```

And this is what I've tried for the timeout:

```
<script>

  window.onload = function(){
        setTimeout(boxMove, 1000);
   };

  function boxMove() {

    $('.box').each( function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        }
    });

    $(this).animate({
        left: '-56%'
    }, 500);

    if ($(this).next().size() > 0) {
        $(this).next().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $(this).prevAll().last().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    }

}

</script>
```

Comment: You are animating the window? `$(this)` is the window.

Comment: `$(this)` is the box because it's under the heading `$('.box').each( function() {`

Comment: No it is not, the indenting shows you that it is not inside of the each, it is the same level. `$(this).animate({` <-- is the line I am talking about

Comment: When I click, the window does not change position, only the box does. That's all I can tell.

Comment: Because I'm using `each()` the `$(this)` represents the currently selected box.

Comment: The $(this) inside the box is the box item, but not the $(this) outside of the each.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I am understanding correctly, you no longer want the click to clear this box, but rather want it to clear automatically 4 seconds after the page loads.

Your code is close, it just looks like you missed some closing brackets when converting the code. Try this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(boxMove, 1000);
};

function boxMove() {
    $('.box').each( function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        }
        $(this).animate({
            left: '-56%'
        }, 500);

        if ($(this).next().size() > 0) {
            $(this).next().animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $(this).prevAll().last().animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 500);
        }
    });
}
```

Assumptions:

1. Your DOM manipulation with jQuery was functioning as you expect it
   to now prior to converting to a timeout.
2. You only need to clear these boxes once and they never return. If they do return and you want to clear them every 4 seconds regularly, change `setTimeout` to `setInterval`.

Comment: This sort of works, but it only shows the first and last box because it's calling the whole function. I want all 5 boxes to be effected and rotate through every four seconds. With your code it waits four seconds, quickly shows the first and last one, then waits another four seconds.

Comment: Without seeing your DOM and CSS it's hard to help you with that issue. Can you post a Fiddle?